# How to i get the SerialPort information of Desktop?

Tags: vb.net

There are two serialports in my computer.

How do I get the serialport information?

(I know about coding of Serialport, but I really want to know about Serialport of my Computer information)

- is it possible to get the information about Serialport of my computer?
- I'm coding in vb.net
- is is possible in vb.net?
- if it possible, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: what do you want to know about serial port? Do you want to find out what number it is?

Comment: No. i want to know about baudrate, parity, databit, handshake at information of serialport.  Of course , I need a serialport Number  too.

Comment: you have to set those parameters yourself, you dont read them from the system, but you set them as you need them to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which information do you want to have about the serial port?

using the MSComm control you can use the following function to determine if the port exists and if it's already in use or not:

```
Public Enum PortAttr
  PortFree = 0
  PortInUse = 1
  PortUnknown = 2
End Enum

Public Function CheckPort(intPort As Integer) As PortAttr
  On Error GoTo ErrorFound
  With MSComm1
    If .PortOpen Then .PortOpen = False
    .CommPort = intPort
    .PortOpen = True
    CheckPort = PortFree
    If .PortOpen = False Then .PortOpen = True
  End With 'MSComm1
Exit Function
ErrorFound:
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case 8002 'port doesnt exist
      CheckPort = PortUnknown
    Case 8005 'port already in use
      CheckPort = PortInUse
    Case Else
      MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & CStr(Err.Number) & " on Port " & CStr(intPort)
  End Select
  On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

You can then loop from 1 to 16 to see if any of these ports exist (usb converters could add extra ports)

```
For intIndex = 1 To 16
  Select Case CheckPort(intIndex)
    Case PortFree
      intFree = intFree + 1
      cboPort.AddItem "Com" & CStr(intIndex), intFree 'add the port to the "free" list
      cboPort.ItemData(intFree) = intIndex
    Case PortInUse
      cboPort.AddItem "Com" & CStr(intIndex) 'add the port to the "in use" ist
  End Select
Next intIndex
```

Comment: Excuse Me, I Use a Vb.Net at VS2013 . but , i could't find  MSComm in VS2013.  is it free component ?

Comment: I dont know. Never used mscomm in vb.net ... i edited your question to tag it as vb.net and also put an edit note in it that you are using vb.net and not vb6 as you said before

Answer (score -1):

**Use the MSComm control in Visual Basic .NET to access serial ports**

Because no Microsoft .NET Framework classes exist to access the communications resources that connected to your computer, you can use the MSComm control in Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0. The MSComm control provides serial communications for your application by enabling the transmission and reception of data through a serial port. To implement basic serial communications by using a modem, follow these steps:
Start Microsoft Visual Studio .NET.
On the File menu, point to New, and then click Project.
Under Project Types, click Visual Basic Projects.
Under Templates, click Console Application.
In the Name box, type MyConsoleApplication, and then click OK.

By default, Module1.vb is created.
Right-click the MyConsoleApplication project, and then click Add Reference.
Click the COM tab, click Microsoft Comm Control 6.0 under Component Name, click Select, and then click OK.

Note To use the MSComm control, you must install the related COM components of Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 on the same computer that has Microsoft Visual Studio .NET installed.

For more information about license issues when you use Visual Basic 6.0 controls in Visual Studio .NET, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
318597 Errors when you use Visual Basic 6.0 controls in Visual Studio .NET
Replace the code in Module1.vb with the following code example.

```
Imports MSCommLib

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'New a MSComm control
        Dim MSComm1 As MSComm
        MSComm1 = New MSComm
        ' Buffer to hold input string.
        Dim Buffer As String
        ' Use the COM1 serial port.
        MSComm1.CommPort = 1
        ' 9600 baud, no parity, 8 data, and 1 stop bit.
        MSComm1.Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
        ' Tell the control to read the whole buffer when Input is used.
        MSComm1.InputLen = 0
        ' Open the serial port.
        MSComm1.PortOpen = True
        Console.WriteLine("Open the serial port.")
        ' Tell the control to make the Input property return text data.
        MSComm1.InputMode() = InputModeConstants.comInputModeText
        'Clear the receive buffer.
        MSComm1.InBufferCount() = 0
        ' Send the attention command to the modem.
        MSComm1.Output = "ATV1Q0" & Chr(13)
        Console.WriteLine("Send the attention command to the modem.")
        Console.WriteLine("Wait for the data to come back to the serial port...")
        ' Make sure that the modem responds with "OK".
        ' Wait for the data to come back to the serial port.
        Do
            Buffer = Buffer & MSComm1.Input
        Loop Until InStr(Buffer, "OK" & vbCrLf)
        ' Read the "OK" response data in the serial port.
        ' Close the serial port.
        Console.WriteLine("Read the OK response data in the serial port.")
        MSComm1.PortOpen = False
        Console.WriteLine("Close the serial port.")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Press CRTL+F5 to build and run this project. You will receive the following output messages:
Open the serial port.
Send the attention command to the modem.
Wait for data to come back to the serial port...
Read the OK response data in the serial port.
Close the serial port.

To read the rest of this you can go here [How to access serial and parallel ports by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/823179)